# how to get decimal the value of decimal type

Tags: sql-server

i am working with MsSql server 2008,

lets say i have table invoices contains column name NetAmount its type is decimal(20,4)

and its data is

```
Netamount, InvoiceID
---------------------
12.1234,     1
20.0120,     2
98.2300,     3
```

i want to retreive through a query  to get only invoices having value not equal to zero in the forth decimal place,in my case this query should only get the first invoice with ID=1 and amount=12.1234 as its forth decimal number is 4 not zero

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One technique:

```
WHERE
   (NetAmount * 10000) % 10 <> 0
```

Another:

```
WHERE
   FLOOR(NetAmount * 1000) <> NetAmount * 1000
```

And

```
WHERE
   ROUND(NetAmount, 3) <> NetAmount
```

Comment: +1 I was halfway through a bunch of nonsense with `LOCATE() CAST() SUBSTRING()` but this makes far more sense.